# Progressive matrix: lines of spades with different orientations

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

This question is from the [international IQ test](https://international-iq-test.com/en/). I don't get the logic around this. What is the answer?

[image: spades with random orientation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is

> e

For the same reason as @CatProgrammer on 1. but also a different requirement

> Each figure (1 spade, 2 spades, 3 spades) in the matrix is pointing up, right or down. Each orientation exactly **one** time per figure.

Comment: I think your answer is valid, but your explanation is wrong. Your solution does not fit with my 2 since the last column does not have two squares whose spades point in the same direction with option e. Your proposed requirement however is valid.

Comment: @Catprogrammer yes youre right, I missed the column part of your argument

Comment: My instant reaction was this answer as well, under a row-wise definition that number-wise col3 contains the difference between col1 and col2, and direction-wise it points in the same direction as the one with the fewest components from cols 1/2. Contrived, but it works.

Comment: yes, the answer is e. thanks for your explaination.

Comment: I failed the IQ test:'(

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is

> A

This is because

> 1. Each row has exactly one square containing 1, 2, and 3 spades respectively.

> 2. Each column and row has exactly two squares whose spades point in the same direction.

> The only option that fits is option a.